# android app crashes when i got the apk shared through gmail or shareIt and not launching

Tags: android, crash, apk, android-install-apk

I developed an application in android studio and tried to share the apk to others through gmail and shareIt application. They are getting the apk file and installed. But when they launch the application, it is crashing. I tested with many devices. Why it is happening like this and what is the solution.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lithium.passenger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
        /*Recycler view*/
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
        /*Card view*/
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
        /*Google services*/
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
        /*Fabric-Crashlytics*/
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        /*Volley lib*/
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
        compile files('libs/tarentoconnectionlib.jar')
        /*Multi dex*/
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }
```

I tested with devices with api 22 and 23

Comment: One thing for sure , it has nothing to do with "how you distribute your apk be it email or anything". **Problem must be your app's compatibility requirements with devices you are testing on**

Comment: apk is of app_debug.apk. My build versions are of 25 and i tested with 22 and 23.

Comment: Build -> Build Apk, and then install that apk and then share.
this problem is due to instant run.

Comment: ya true. Its because of instant run.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no `logs` which would help us to know the exact reason for `crash`

Still from your description, it seems..

> They are getting the apk file and installed

Getting installed *only means their devices are higher end* than your `minSDKVersion` , ie. `16`.

Installing alone wont guarantee proper functioning unless you do so.

> I tested with devices with api 22 and 23

The problem might be --Some where you are *using dependencies/features which are not their in lower* `API` devices and you might not have taken preventive measures to handle that.

That may be the reason for crash on lower end devices.

If you post `Logs`, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the build from `Build->Generate APk`and then install at your device and share it with others.